# More than 255 Linux GRE tunnels

Tags: linux, networking, tunneling

Is it possible to set up more than 255 GRE tunnels in Linux? It seems that 255 is the default maximum, but is there any way to increase the limit?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: It doesn't work. I suppose I should rephrase the question to "how can I"

Comment: Maybe include the command you are running and what the error is as well, so people have more of an idea of what you attempting.

Comment: The command is `ip tunnel add gre1 mode gre remote 172.19.20.21 local 172.16.17.18 ttl 255`. Once I've done this with `gre2`, `gre3`, etc, more than 255 times, I start getting an error that there is no buffer space left. In practice the names don't actually matter - I can add `gre500` and it still works - but no matter what, there can't be more than 255 in total.

Comment: The [man page for ip](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) implies there is a limit of 255 routing tables total for the system.

Comment: Routing tables, sure, but does each device get its own routing table? I managed to get exactly 255 GRE tunnels, even with other interfaces present; I'd think that if each had its own routing table, it'd have capped out at 255 = (num GRE + num other interfaces).

Comment: This is kind of gross, but can you set up multiple network namespaces with `ip netns`, and at least have 255 gre tunnels per namespace?

Comment: Hey, that works; thanks! You just saved me from having to implement a custom tunneling solution in userland :P